# How to check source file into version control on successful processing?

Tags: latexmk, git

I want to `git add file.tex` and `git commit -m ‘successful compile’` (or similar) every time LatexMk successfully completes building a PDF. I'm guessing I can put something in `latexmkrc`, but my Perl-foo isn’t strong enough to know what. Is this possible without significant work?

Comment: I don't know if or if not this is possible with latexmk, but just in case you don't find an answer, you could try the other way round: use a git pre commit hook to call latexmk.